# Dynamic n strings with each string length be random (depend on user input)

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing how to dynamically allocate memory for n strings with each string be however long you want.
So I know to use double pointers, but can't understand how to allocate each string with the right amount of space.
My code:

```
     int i,n;
     char **str;

    printf("Enter n (strings of chracters): ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    str = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));

    printf("Enter strings one by one:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        str[i] = (char*)malloc(//SOMETHING//*sizeof(char));
        gets(str[i]);
    }
```

I tried to be cheeky and put gets() first like this

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        gets(str[i]);
        str[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(str[i])*sizeof(char));
```

but that obviously is wrong, I can't read string then allocate it.
So is there anyway to replace //SOMETHING// with the length of each string?
Thanks for reading my amateur post.

Comment: The loop condition `i <= n` will lead to you using `n` as an index, which will be out of bounds. For an array of `n` elements, what is the highest valid index?

Comment: OOPS my bad then, it's supposed to be ``i<n`` right?

Comment: On another note: ***Never ever*** use `gets`. It's an old and [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function that have even been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: A string cannot be really "as long we want". You need to choose: either there is a maximum size harcoded in your program OR you ask the user what is the maximum size for each string.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to waste space and only allocate enough memory to fit the string, then you need to read character by character until you read the newline, reallocating (using [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)) as needed.

Perhaps something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    size_t current_size = 1;  // Start with space for one character, the null-terminator
    str[i] = malloc(current_size);
    str[i][0] = '\0';  // String null-terminator

    int ch;  // Must be an int for the EOF check to work

    // Read characters one by one, until eof (or error) or newline
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    {
        char *temp_str = realloc(str[i], current_size + 1);  // Increase memory by one character
        if (temp_str == NULL)
        {
            // Error allocating memory, do something useful here
            break;
        }

        str[i] = temp_str;
        str[i][current_size - 1] = ch;  // Add the newly read character
        str[i][current_size] = '\0';  // Add the new null-terminator
        ++current_size;  // Increase the size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't magically 'predict' how long a string will be before a user enters it! However, you *can* assign a 'working buffer' of a given *maximum* length, read into that, then assign the required memory and copy that string.

You could use a combination of `malloc`, `strlen` and `strcpy` to do this, but the [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) function will do it all for you in one fell swoop:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 5000

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    char** str;
    char buffer[MAXLENGTH]; // Working buffer to read in strings

    printf("Enter n (strings of chracters): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    str = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));

    printf("Enter strings one by one:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fgets(buffer, MAXLENGTH, stdin);
        // You probably want to remove the trailing newline from the string:
        if (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n') buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
        str[i] = strdup(buffer); // Will only allocate enough memory - not 5000 each time.
    }

    // Show the results (to verify operation) ...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    // And don't forget to free the allocated buffers:
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) free(str[i]);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, the `gets` function has been removed from the C library: use `fgets()` instead (as shown). See: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10871073).

Also, you don't need to cast the result of `malloc`: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073).